# Python 3 because of limited knowledge code won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Current Code:**

```
import random
numbers=[]
for i in range(20):
    spam = random.randint(1,30)
    print(spam)
```

I would like to insert `spam` into the `numbers` but this is where I am stuck.

**Expected Result:**

List of 20 random numbers

Comment: `numbers.append(spam)` within your `for` loop is what you're looking for.

Comment: Your list is ``numbers``, not ``spam``. You're saying you didn't find any guide on how to fill a list in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, but instead of just printing your random number, you need to append it to your list `numbers`. Simply add the line `numbers.append(spam)` to the body of your `for` loop.

(You can remove the print statement if you don't need in anymore.)

There's more elegant ways to construct this list (see the list comprehension answer) but at your level `append` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code**

```
import random
numbers=[]
for i in range(20):
    spam = random.randint(1,30)
    numbers.append(spam)
print numbers
```

**Output**

```
[14, 19, 5, 20, 17, 8, 7, 28, 18, 3, 26, 9, 10, 15, 28, 20, 8, 26, 13, 16]
```

Yours might be different since they are random numbers

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use list comprehension:

```
numbers = [random.randint(1, 30) for _ in range(20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import random
# np.random.randint can take 3 arguments low, high and size. 
# In this case an array of 20 (size) random integers from range 1 (low) to 30 (high) 
# will be printed. The range is inclusive of 1 and exclusive of 30.    

spam =  np.random.randint(1,30,20); print(spam)

[ 5 12 16 19 27 19 27  9 12  2 21  7  7 12  4 13  4 28 21  5]
```